# Calculate a function for each element of a matrix using another vector as input in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I want to calculate the variables `fn_x` and `Fn_x` by avoiding the loop from the following codes:

```
y <- seq(0,2,0.01)
z <- sort(rexp(100,1))
U <- round(runif(100), 0)
myfun <- function(x) 0.75 * (1-x^2) * (abs(x)<1) 

fn_x <- matrix(0, length(y), 1)
Fn_x <- matrix(0, length(y), 1)
for(j in 1:length(y)){
  fn_x[j] <- (1/(100*2)) * sum(myfun((y[j]-z)/2))
  Fn_x[j] <- (1/100)*sum(I(z <=y[j] & U==1))
  }
```

My function is using two different matrices with different dimensions for calculating each element, so the function `apply` is not working in this case. Is it possible to solve this problem without using any package?

Comment: For these specific operations, it seems that you could use `f2 = (1 / (100 * 2)) * colSums(myfun(outer(z, y, "-") / 2))` to create `fn_x` and `F2 = (1 / 100) * colSums(outer(z, y, "<=") & as.logical(U))` for `Fn_x`; `all.equal(c(fn_x), f2); all.equal(c(Fn_x), F2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already preallocating vectors before executing the loop, you're doing a lot of the heavy lifting needed to speed up calculations. At this point, `data.table` or pure implementation in C++ using e.g. `Rcpp` package would boost the speed.

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  original = {
    fn_x <- matrix(NA, length(y), 1)
    Fn_x <- matrix(NA, length(y), 1)
    for(j in 1:length(y)){
      fn_x[j] <- (1/(100*2)) * sum(myfun((y[j]-z)/2))
      Fn_x[j] <- (1/100)*sum(I(z <=y[j] & U==1))
    }
  },
  new =  {
    fn_x2 <- sapply(y, FUN = function(x, z) {
      (1/(100*2)) * sum(myfun((x-z)/2))
    }, z = z)

    Fn_x2 <- sapply(y, FUN = function(x, z, U) {
      (1/100) * sum(I(z <= x & U == 1))
    }, z = z, U = U)
  }
)

Unit: milliseconds
     expr      min        lq     mean    median       uq      max
 original 9.550934 10.407091 12.13302 10.895803 11.95638 22.87758
      new 8.734813  9.126127 11.18128  9.264137 10.12684 87.68265
```